# Получение удаленной страницы

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, парсер, vk-mini-apps

Пытаюсь сделать vk mini app, которое получало бы `HTML` содержимое страницы, которая лежит на другом сервере.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать, используя `nodejs` и, желательно, `react`.

Пробовал использовать `fetch` и `XMLRequest`, но не могу получить ответ, т. к. "Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://example.com/. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»)"

Функция с `fetch`:

```js
    const fuction = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://example.com/', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS заголовки - это отдельная тема, которую, желательно, самостоятельно изучить. Например [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Быстрое решение - это использование т.н. cors proxy серверов. Ты делаешь запрос не напрямую, а через cors сервер и он уже добавляет нужные заголовки.
Список серверов можешь посмотреть [здесь](https://nordicapis.com/10-free-to-use-cors-proxies/).

Можно также написать собственный сервер, на той же Node.js и также проксировать через него запросы. Можешь скачать мой сервер с GitHub и доработать под свои нужды, если нужно. [Ссылка](https://github.com/NikitaVagin/cors-proxy-serv)